# Integration on Manifolds - separating the manifold into two sets

Tags: calculus, manifolds

Is it true that for a k-manifold with boundary $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and subset $A \subset M$, and k-form $w$ on $M$,  $\int_M w = \int_{M - A}  w + \int_A w$? (Call this Equation 1)

I'm not sure here, because on the one hand, the integral $\int_M w$ is defined to be  $\int_c w$ where $c:W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a k-cube which is also a coordinate system. The fact that $c$ is a coordinate system means that $c$ is injective. Injectivity leads me to believe that Equation 1 is correct, since the above equation makes sense if I think about it pulled back to $[0,1]^k$.

On the other hand, if I let $A = \partial M$, then $\int_M w = \int_{M - \partial M}  w + \int_{\partial M} w$. But the last term $\int_{\partial M} w$ doesn't make sense to me, since $w$ is a $k$-form but $\partial M$ is a $k-1$ manifold. So I'm tempted to also say that Equation 1 doesn't hold

Which understanding is correct?

Comment: $A$ can't be just any subset.  Take $M=[0,1]$ with coordinate $x$, $w=\mathrm{d}x$ and $A$ a nonmeasurable subset, for example.